# Greedy Algorithm for Convolutional neural network (CNN)

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, convolution

I had a specific question about Andrew Howard's "Some Improvements on Deep Convolutional Neural Network Based Image Classification." In the paper under section 3.3, he describes using a simple greedy algorithm to reduce the number of predictions from 90 to 10, starting with the best prediction. How can you decide which image crop will produce the best prediction? My guess is we decide on the 10 best crops outputting the 10 best predictions during the validation set, and just use those 10 crop during subsequent prediction? Or is it just any 10 random crops that occur during prediction?

Comment: I am relatively sure this is what he wanted to express. It is, however, not clear from the publication. So I've just sent him an e-mail. Remind me in a couple of days if I don't post the answer here.

Comment: Any word from the author regarding the methodology of the greedy algorithm?

Comment: Nope. No reaction.